# Hibernate queries to postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, tomcat

I've got jsp webapp on my VPS host with tomcat 7 as server. I'm using Hibernate 3 and PostgreSQL. All methods in my class DBManager (responsible for db services, connection, queries) use almost the same structure:

```
 Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    =======
    HERE HQL QUERY/session.get/update/save etc are executed
    =======
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

The problem is that my VPS after some time (using my webapp) shows many idle postgres processes which causes server overloading and e.x VPS kills Java or refuses connection to DB. What can I do to remove the problem? Is this a problem caused by my code or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. What I did wrong was creating new factory in each instance of class. Now I added static reference everywhere and it is working pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `session.close()` in `try/finally` block:

```
try {
  session.beginTransaction();
  =======
  HERE HQL QUERY/session.get/update/save etc are executed
  =======
  session.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
  // handle the exception, e.g. session.getTransaction().rollback();
} finally {
  session.close(); // this will require another try/catch
}
```

If exception happens somewhere in your code, the session doesn't get closed and leaks resources.

Comment: Thx for answer, I'll test it right now. But to be precise: try{...}catch(){handle exception}finally{session.close() in another try/finally} ?

Comment: Have a look at this article, it covers your scenario and has code samples: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/bestpractices/closing_and_releasing_jdbc_resources.html --it refers to JDBC connections but pretty much the same applies to hibernate session.

Comment: Hey, I made a use of your solution. Did as you said, postgres processes still stay at my server as idle. Every action that is undertaken and causes query to db is visible later as idle connection to my database...

Comment: Are you using a connection pool? If so, having some idle connections is normal. Obviously if your connection count grows non stop then it's a problem.

Comment: I'm not. I've checked that hibernate has its own, called c3p0 but I can't find a way to use it without spring or maven. I mean: added properties to the hibernate.cfg but getting an error: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider